error UserWarning: Your input ran out of data; interrupting training."
I am writing now cnn model and trying to initialize it with model.fit(). I am trying to do according to guide https://www.kaggle.com/code/vencerlanz09/98-fire-classification-cnn-mobilenetv2
Apparently when i initialized model.fit(). it runs 1,3,5th epochs fine but for some reason skips even numbered epochs  with following error: Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least steps_per_epoch * epochs batches.
Another point to mention is that in my first epoch, cnn algorithm somewhat starts from accuracy of 1.0 and slowly drops down instead of gradually increasing from 0

My code is this
import os 
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import urllib.request
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdbourke/tensorflow-deep-learning/main/extras/helper_functions.py"
filename = "helper_functions.py"
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from helper_functions import create_tensorboard_callback, plot_loss_curves, unzip_data, compare_historys, walk_through_dir, pred_and_plot 
project_path = "C:\\Users\\immaf\\Desktop\\Extended essay" 

images = []
labels = []
for subfolder in os.listdir(project_path):
    print(f"Processing folder: {subfolder}")  # Print folder name for debugging
    
    subfolder_path = os.path.join(project_path, subfolder)
    if not os.path.isdir(subfolder_path):
        continue

    # List images in the folder
    for image_filename in os.listdir(subfolder_path):
        image_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, image_filename)
        images.append(image_path)
        labels.append(subfolder)

# Create DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({'image': images, 'label': labels})
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10)
# Split the data into training (70%), validation (15%), and test (15%)
train_data, temp_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.3, random_state=42, stratify=data['label'])
val_data, test_data = train_test_split(temp_data, test_size=0.5, random_state=42, stratify=temp_data['label'])
batch_size = 32
image_size = (256, 256)
# Training data generator with augmentation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1.0/255,  # Rescale pixel values to [0, 1]
    rotation_range=20,  # Randomly rotate images
    width_shift_range=0.2,  # Randomly shift images horizontally
    height_shift_range=0.2,  # Randomly shift images vertically
    shear_range=0.2,  # Shear angle in counter-clockwise direction
    zoom_range=0.2,  # Randomly zoom into images
    horizontal_flip=True,  # Randomly flip images
    fill_mode='nearest'  # Fill in newly created pixels
)


# Validation and test data generator (only rescaling)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)


# Create generators for training, validation, and test sets
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_data,
    x_col='image',
    y_col='label',
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',  # Use 'categorical' for multi-class classification
    shuffle=True,
)
val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=val_data,
    x_col='image',
    y_col='label',
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=test_data,
    x_col='image',
    y_col='label',
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical'
)
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers
learning_rate = 0.001  # Adjust learning rate
filter_size = (3, 3)  # Size of the convolution filters
num_filters = 32  # Number of filters in the first Conv2D layer
dropout_rate = 0.5  # Dropout rate
pooling_layer_type = 'max'  # 'max' or 'average' pooling
strides = (1, 1)  # Stride for the convolutional layers

# Create the model
model = models.Sequential()

# First convolutional layer
model.add(layers.Conv2D(num_filters, filter_size, strides=strides, activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))

# Add pooling layer
if pooling_layer_type == 'max':
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
elif pooling_layer_type == 'average':
    model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Second convolutional layer
model.add(layers.Conv2D(num_filters * 2, filter_size, strides=strides, activation='relu'))  # Double the filters for deeper layers
if pooling_layer_type == 'max':
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
elif pooling_layer_type == 'average':
    model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Third convolutional layer
model.add(layers.Conv2D(num_filters * 4, filter_size, strides=strides, activation='relu'))  # Increase filters
if pooling_layer_type == 'max':
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
elif pooling_layer_type == 'average':
    model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Flattening the output
model.add(layers.Flatten())

# Fully connected layer
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))

# Dropout layer
model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_rate))

# Output layer
# Change from binary classification to multi-class classification
num_classes = 2
model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))  # Replace num_classes with the actual number of classes


# Compile the model with binary crossentropy with specified learning rate
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',  # Change to binary crossentropy
              metrics=['accuracy'])


# Model summary to check the structure
model.summary()
print(f"Total training samples: {len(train_data)}")
print(f"Batch size: {batch_size}")
print(f"Steps per epoch: {len(train_data) // batch_size}")


history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch= (len(train_data) + batch_size - 1) // batch_size,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=len(val_generator),
    epochs=20,
    callbacks=[]
)



I tried to change  steps_per_epoch from len(train_generator) to len(train_data) // batch_size
Doing so did not solve the problem. The dataset is around 900 images so i doubt it is a problem with small dataset size

Maybe soluble (if not already tried) by selecting to run on a TPU (Tensor Processing Unit)?
I had the same/similar problem: alternate epochs had no validation done. My compilation had four Conv2D convolutional layers with MaxPool2D max pooling, and used tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory rather than ImageDataGenerator (though that's probably immaterial). Run in CoLab, selecting for use either "CPU" or "T-4 GPU" via the 'Runtime/Change runtime type' CoLab menu, those alternately skipped validations occurred.
However, on changing to use a "TPU v2-8" (available for free at time of use), the validations were then, in contrast, carried out for each and every epoch.

i dont have tpu, any other solutions? im using jupyter lab if it helps

Hmm, I see - my apologies, I have no more ideas at the moment. CoLab with CPU/GPU is still doing only epochs 1,3,5 for me too. Maybe you could try copy/paste from Jupyter Lab into CoLab - although that would perhaps be only a temporary solution as Colab's TPU use is limited. (I wish I knew how to analyse Colab error/warinng logs, that might give a clue.). Hmm.
